# Automating a Report from latest Data entry

Tags: excel, vba, database, ms-word

I am trying to Create a report automatically when new data is entered into a database. The report is Based on a report I already created. Here is the code:

```
Sub CreateReport()
    Dim databaseRange As Range
    Dim reportRange As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long
    Dim newReport As Worksheet
    
    'Get the last row of data in the database
    lastRow = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database").Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row
    
    'Set the range of data in the database
    Set databaseRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Database").Range("R3C1:R" & lastRow & "C129")
    
    'Set the range of data in the report
    Set reportRange = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("report").Range("R1C12:R76C12")
    
    'Create a new worksheet for the report
    Set newReport = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets.Add
    
    'Copy the report format to the new worksheet
    reportRange.Copy newReport.Range("A1")
    
    'Copy the most up-to-date row of data from the database to the new report
    databaseRange.Rows(lastRow - 2).Copy newReport.Range("A4")
    
    'Rename the new worksheet as "New Report"
    newReport.Name = "New Report"
    
End Sub
```

I believe the problem has to deal with the code trying to draw from the "database" and I list "R3C1:R" & lastRow & "C129".

Please note I am doing this in R1C1 Reference Style in Excel which could be a problem but I'm not sure.

Comment: Is there some reason you want to use R1C1 reference style?

Comment: Why is this question tagged `ms-word` and `visio`? Is it related to them?